# jQuery next/previous buttons not working properly in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var list = jQuery('#content-list .mask ul').get(0);
    var mask = jQuery('#content-list .mask').get(0);
    var next = jQuery('#content-list .next').get(0);
    var previous = jQuery('#content-list .previous').get(0);

    var listHeight = parseInt(jQuery('#content-list').first().attr('listheight'));

    var isAnimating = false;
    var duration = 'slow';
    var easing = 'swing';
    var min = Math.floor(jQuery(list).innerHeight()/listHeight)*-listHeight;
    var max = 0;
    var current = 0;

    if(list) {

        jQuery(mask).height(listHeight-20);
        jQuery(previous).addClass('disabled');

        if (current <= min)
            jQuery(next).addClass('disabled');

        jQuery(next).bind('click', function(){
            var elements;
            var callback;
            if(!isAnimating) {

                isAnimating = true;

                current -= listHeight;
                if (current <= min) {
                    current = min;
                    jQuery(this).addClass('disabled');
                }

                if (current < max) {
                    jQuery(previous).removeClass('disabled');
                }

                callback = function() { 
                    isAnimating = false;
                }

                jQuery(list)
                .animate({'margin-top': current+'px'}, duration, easing, callback);
            }

            return false;

        });

        jQuery(previous).bind('click', function(){

            var elements;
            var callback;

            if(!isAnimating) {

                isAnimating = true;
                current += listHeight;

                if (current >= max) {
                    current = max;
                    jQuery(this).addClass('disabled');  
                }

                if (current > min) {
                    jQuery(next).removeClass('disabled');
                }

                callback = function() { 
                    isAnimating = false;
                }

                jQuery(list)
                .animate({'margin-top': current+'px'}, duration, easing, callback);
            }

            return false;

        });

    }

});
```

It works great in Firefox but fails in IE7...instead of scrolling nicely, it scrolls about 1/4 of the distance that it should and the event doesn't appear to fire consistently when I press the "next" button.

I suspect that this has to do with some CSS I changed as this code was working before...but I am not sure where to start. I looked through each variable using Firequery and in Firefox at least it appears to be giving me the correct measurements and the items such as "list" are the HTML elements I am looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did get this working with some help...it turns out that one selector I was using in my jQuery lacked IE's "hasLayout" so the scrolling wasn't being implemented correctly.

Things that worked for me:

- use Javascript alerts to see what is getting called and what isn't
- try "position: relative" on the selector that doesn't seem to be working properly in IE7
- if your selector does not "haveLayout" (should read hasLayout: -1 in the IE DEV toolbar) then try adding zoom: 1